# ID in CSS getting overwritten by <a> color property

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the table creation. The first column appears the same as the rest of the links namely "Edit", "Details" and "Delete"

```
<tr>
        <td>
           @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.ID }, htmlAttributes: new {id = "myclass"})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
```

### Below is my CSS class

```
a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*.linkproperties{
    color: aqua;
}
#myclass .linkproperties { color: blue;} works fine*/
```

### #myclass .a {color: blue;} /*does not work*/

As commented above, If I create my own class (.linkproperties), attach it to "Edit", "Details" and "Delete" actionlinks and override it with #myclass it works, but the same does not occur with #myclass .a{color:blue}

Comment: You'd better provide HTML that you've got in browser, otherwise it is not clear what exactly that @Html.ActionLink does.

Comment: @c-smile - this is a ASP.NET MVC method for generating links.  The rendered HTML would look like a typical link <a id="linkproperties" href="someRelativePath">Text</a>.  He did tag it appropriately so I am not sure posting the generated HTML will be much help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, you should explicitly override the declaration using the `!important` attribute in your CSS.

```
a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.linkproperties{
    color: aqua !important;
```

This will cause the browsers to ignore the typical inheritance and flowdown of CSS attributes and apply any property with the `!important` attribute regardless if something further up or down the line would typically override it.

**Edit**

Read the wrong portion of your question.  My principle still applies, but needs to be moved to a new spot.  Also, get rid of the . in front of the a, .a is an Id, a is a hyperlink.

The CSS

```
#myClass a {color: blue !important;}
```

The HTML

```
 <td class="myClass">
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
```

Lastly, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rA6tU/) showing the working results (using actual a links instead of @Html.ActionLinks

Comment: Hi Tommy. Thank you for your input. Here I have successfully implemented a class called ".linkproperties" which I can include in my code and override with my "myclass" ID. However, when I do not use .linkproperties in my code and try to override the  <a> color property using the "myclass" ID it does not happen so. I have attached a copy of how the CSS looks as per Firebug

Comment: Also, the myClass should be on the <td class="myClass"> if you want to override how links look inside of an element with the class of myClass

Comment: 'a {
    -moz-text-decoration-style: solid;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    outline-color: -moz-use-text-color;
    
}
#myclass .a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 255) !important;
}'

Comment: Thank you Tommy. Your suggestion worked. Here is the change I made  '<td id="myclass">
           @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>'  Works perfectly fine along with the change in the CSS that you recommended. Thanks alot

Comment: @user2955080 - awesome, I added a JS fiddle just in case.  Also, be sure to mark the answer as answered (click the green checkmark) if this helped you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your outputted HTML (A JSFiddle would be nice), it's tough to tell.  But nine times out of ten with issues like you're having, it's a CSS specificity issue.  http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/